# Cannot update some apps

Tags: google-play-store, updates

I am using Android 8.1, Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime, Google Play Store v 23.8.08-21, Google Play Services v 20.50.16.
Everything installed from the Play Store.

For a few apps that I have installed, whenever I try to update them in Play, they would finish downloading, and start downloading again. After several times, the process finishes and I still have the same old version.
I can still update most of the apps, or install new apps.

For instance, I had this problem with Waze. In addition, the total size that was shown was different from the actual size (36.22MB vs. 78.51MB), but download goes up to the actual size.
I tried uninstalling Waze, to see if this fixed the issue, and now I cannot install it again, so *I am in a worse situation than before*.

[image]

This problem is similar, but not the same, to another I had previously reported [Cannot install / update apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/207441/cannot-install-update-apps)

I reinstalled Android in between.

**How can I solve this problem?**

I have already

1. Cleared Cache from Google Play Store and Google Play Services.
2. Removed my Google account and Added it again.
3. Rebooted phone.

I did not try Clear Data from Google Play Store, since there were people reporting that the phone became unusable after that.

Comment: Are the installed apps installed from PlayStore? Because if the app signature does not match the installation may fail. What Android and PlayStore version is installed on your device?

Comment: @Robert - I have added all info you asked about

Comment: As only a few apps are affected I would try to install the update by sideloading the app from apkmirror.com/apkpure.com or similar web site. As you already have the app installed the app has to have the same cryptographic signature hence you don't have to fear that the downloaded app may be forged or manipulated if it installs as update. Hopefully this fixes the update problems.