# Cannot move app to SD card

Tags: applications, internal-storage, external-sd, storage

I am using Android 8.1 in a Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime.

Some apps show a *Storage used* option. This means they can be stored in Device memory or External storage.
I mean to move all apps to External storage whenever possible.

In some cases, when I select
*Storage used* -> *CHANGE* to move to SD card, after 100% completion the app is still in Device memory.

**Is there any way to solve this?**

Notes:

1. [Cannot move app to SD card: "Not enough storage space"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/212891/cannot-move-app-to-sd-card-not-enough-storage-space) is a similar question from me (although not the same).
2. I would avoid removing the app and reinstalling, just to try, since I have [this problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233492/cannot-update-some-apps).

Comment: native App2SD is not related to android version, it is a decision of app developer. if app allows it, note that external storage is still another location in your phones memory (emulated storage). you can however map MicroSD Card with [\[adoptable-storage\]](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) as emulated storage location (unfortunately not for FBE encrypted devices with android 8.1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SD card not appearing when formatted as internal](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213312/sd-card-not-appearing-when-formatted-as-internal)

Comment: *"Some apps show a Storage used option. This means they can be stored in Device memory or External storage."* This might not be correct. It's the `android:installLocation` attribute which decides if the app is movable or not. See my answers to related questions: [How to free Internal Storage by moving data or using symlink / bind-mount with Adoptable Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214706/218526) and [How to move apps from internal to external storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214568/218526)

Comment: @IrfanLatif - I will read your links. In the meantime, why would the OS show an option for choosing the storage location of an app if it is not movable? 
If it's the `android:installLocation` attribute which decides if the app is movable or not, I would expect the OS to check that attribute and show the option as per it.
Otherwise, what controls the appearance of such an option?

Comment: I've never been a user of Samsung device, neither I ever moved apps to external storage except for experimenting. So I'm not sure about it. That's why I said *might be*. Logically you are correct. But you can check the said attribute in the app's manifest to confirm.

Comment: Nevertheless i got the feeling you missed the point of my comment. after moving to SD card, app is still in device memory, **because */sdcard* is still in device memory**. see linked question **how to solve this** from command line, when your ROM does not provide this setting in gui